# C# SaveFileDialog setting one from multiple extensions Automatically adding extension when extensions are not typed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, savefiledialog

I am using `SaveFileDialog` to save an image.

The filter of the control is : `PNG|*png;|GIF|*gif;|BMP|*bmp;|JPEG|*jpg;*jpeg;`

However, if the extension is not typed in filename, it does not automatically add the extension.

I know that i can set a `DefaultExt`, however, I do not know how to handle this when it comes to selecting from multiple extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is that the filter you're using  isn't correct according to the rules of [`FileDialog.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx) (you've left out the `.` characters in the patterns). Before `SaveFileDialog` auto-adds the extension, it first validates the selected filter. In your case, this validation is failing; which is why the auto-addition isn't working as you expect.

Try the following filter:

```
PNG|*.png|GIF|*.gif|BMP|*.bmp|JPEG|*.jpg;*.jpeg
```

An explicit `dialog.AddExtension = true;` won't hurt here although I believe that's the default.

Comment: oh! i also figured out that the filter was the problem so i copy&pasted the filter from other program and it worked well, but i did not know why,,, and......... thank you for telling me that the missing DOT was the reason

Comment: @jn4kim: Yeah, and you don't need the `AddExtension = true`, so this is your actual issue.

Comment: +1 You're right, his problem was with the filter itself. Actually the dialog will always add the extension, AddExtension will just change how it'll be picked. Please @jn4kim unaccept my answer, it's wrong.

Comment: @Adriano Ok, your answer was also helpful though ^^;